# json not working in javascript in bottle framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, bottle

I am now totally confused with the usage of data structures in bottle...

Now I am using a Jquery tool ztree to build a tree in my web page.

index.py:

```
data = [{'name':'1'},
        {'name':'2'}]
return template('index', data)
```

But, when I try to get data in my JavaScript code as `{{data}}`, and then pass it to ztree to build my tree, it shows nothing.

On the other hand, if I pass `[{'name':1'},{'name':2}]` directly to ztree, a tree is built as expected. So what's the difference between the two?

Comment: Is `{'name':1'}` an intended typo?

Comment: You have some mis-matching apostrophes in `[{'name':1'},{'name':2}]`, here: (`:1'}`)

Comment: Is the extra `'` after `1` intended or is that a typo? Could that be causing the problem?

Comment: sorry i missed it when i post it..

Answer (score 3):

You are passing in a *Python* structure, which a Javascript framework won't know anything about. The string representation interpolated into a template may look a lot like a JavaScript structure but there are (many) differences.

Translate it to a structure Javascript *can* read by using the `json` module:

```
import json

# ...
data = json.dumps(data)
```

then interpolate that into your Javascript code as a (unescaped) variable:

```
data = {{!data}};
```

Comment: I tried this yesterday, not working either. And when I try to print type(data) in my tpl, turns out it's str.

Comment: actually, the problem becomes that, when i pass some data, a dict or a json.dumps str, to my template, i can not access it in my javascript code like js_data = {{data}}, the only way that won't go wrong is js_data = "{{data}}". But that ain't show me nothing neither.

Comment: Seem if you user json.dumps() in your code, you will get quots in it when you get it in javascript. As in my example, you got [{&quots;name&quots;:&quots;1&quots;{&quots;name&quots;:&quots;2&quots;}]. Does this mean that json.dumps() is not working?

Comment: Found an answer here:http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.bottle.general/1123

Comment: Here i quot:Templates escape certain HTML special-characters in strings to avoid XSS vulnerabilities. We added single and double quotes to the list of dangerous characters recently.To disable auto-escaping, use {{!vaname}} instead of {{varname}} in your
template.

Comment: @ShadyXu: My apologies; indeed, you need to add the `!` to prevent escaping.